# How is the subdifferential of the $l_2$ norm at $x=0$ the polar of the unit ball?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I was reviewing subdifferentials, and my professor writes on the board that the subdifferential of the $l_2$ norm at $x=0$ is the polar of the unit ball?

I tried to work through this myself:

Let $\Phi(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is a closed, non-empty convex set.
$$\Phi(x)=||x||$$

I know the following:
$$\Phi^*(z)=\sup_{x\in C}\{\langle z,x\rangle-\Phi(x)\}$$

and I know that the support function of the set $C$ is the dual of the indicator function:

$$\sigma_C(x)=\delta^*_C(x):=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x\in C \\
     \infty &\text{else} \\
\end{array} 
\right. $$

and I also know that it is equal to the sup:

$$\sigma_C(x) = \sup_z\{\langle z,x\rangle\}$$

And I know the definition of the subdifferential at the point $x$ for the set $C$ is this:

$$\partial\Phi(x)=\{z\hspace{0.2cm}|\hspace{0.2cm} \Phi(y)\ge \Phi(x)+ \langle z,y-x\rangle \hspace{0.2cm}\forall y \}$$

But I do not understand how to put these definitions together to get this:

$$\partial\Phi(0)=\mathbb{B}^o$$  which is the polar of the unit ball.  How are the steps used to get this?

*edit* :: I am also interested in how these things relate to each other:  the $\sigma_C(x)$, and $\partial\Phi(x)$, (if at all) ?

Answer (score 2):

Following the derivation in Example 3.3 of the book by Beck (First-Order Methods in Optimization), I will provide the derivation for a general norm and then answer specifically for $\ell_2$ norm.

We have
$$
\Phi (x) = \| x \|
$$
and we are interested in its subdifferential at $x=0$ i.e. $\partial \, \Phi (0)$.

The correct answer is
$$
\partial \, \Phi (0) = \{ g \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| g \|_* \leq 1 \}.
$$
This is the unit ball of the dual norm $\| \cdot \|_*$. It is not polar of the unit ball.

Note that $g \in \partial \, \Phi (0)$ if and only if

$$
\Phi (y) \geq \Phi (0) + \langle g , y - 0 \rangle  \, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
i.e.
$$
\| y \| \geq \langle g , y \rangle \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
In other words
$$
g \in \partial \, \Phi (0) \iff \langle g , y \rangle \leq \| y \| \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
We first show that if $g$ belongs to the unit ball of the dual norm, then it is a subgradient.

If $\| g \|_* \leq 1$ then, by generalized Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$
\langle g , y \rangle \leq \| g \|_* \| y \| \leq \| y \| \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$

Thus, if $\| g \|_* \leq 1$ then, $g$ is subgradient of $\Phi$ at $x=0$.

In the reverse direction, we will show that if $g$ is a subgradient, then
$\| g \|_* \leq 1$ must hold.

Assuming $g \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to be a subgradient, we have:
$$
  \langle g , y \rangle \leq \| y \| \; \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
Then it will also hold for all $ \| y \| \leq 1$. Maximizing the L.H.S. over the unit ball, we get

$$
\| g \|_* = \underset{y : \| y \| \leq 1}{\sup} \langle g, y \rangle \leq \| y \| 
$$
holds for some $y=y_0$ s.t. $ \| y_0 \| \leq 1$. Thus, $\| g \|_* \leq 1$
must hold.

Combining, we get the result that:

$$
\partial \, \Phi (0) = \{ g \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| g \|_* \leq 1 \}.
$$

Finally, for the special case of $\ell_2$ norm $\Phi (x) = \| x \|_2$, the norm is self dual hence the answer in this case is the unit ball of the $\ell_2$ norm  $\{ g \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| g \|_2 \leq 1 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the subdifferential we get for $\Phi(0)$ the following
$$\partial\Phi(0)=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\Phi(y)\geqslant \Phi(0)+\langle z,y-0\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n\}=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}||y||\geqslant \langle z,y\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n\}\\=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}||y||\geqslant \langle z,y\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n, ||y||<1\}\cup \{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}||y||\geqslant \langle z,y\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n, ||y||\geqslant 1\}
\\=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}||y||\geqslant \langle z,y\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n, ||y||<1\}\cup\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}1\geqslant \langle z,\frac{y}{||y||}\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n\}=\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n|\hspace{0.2cm}1\geqslant \langle z,y\rangle,\forall y\in \mathbb{B}\}:=\mathbb{B}^o$$
Note that $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ we have $y/||y||\in \mathbb{B}$ where $\mathbb{B}$ is the unit ball.

Comment: sorry to bother about this, but can you please make your answer a little more easy to read?

Comment: Hey Arian.  Thanks a lot, but I do not understand how you got from the second to last line, to the last line.  Can you please make that a bit more explicit?  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I understand that you divided by the norm of $y$ between the 3rd to last line and the 2nd to last line.  Are you allowed to do that because $||y||\ge 1$ and hence $||y|| \ne 0$?

Comment: @Hunle yes for any $y\neq 0$ you can divide by its norm.

Comment: I'm still not following you completely.  In the second to last line, I do not understand why you drop the restriction that $||y|| \ge 1$?  Seems to me like that is still a necessary for this line to make sense:  $\{z\in\mathbb{R}^n | ||y|| \ge <z,y> \forall y \mathbb{R}^n , ||y|| \lt 1\} \bigcup \{z\in \mathbb{R}^n | 1 \ge <z, \frac{y}{||y||}>, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$.  But in the $\{z\in \mathbb{R}^n | 1 \ge <z, \frac{y}{||y||}>, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n\}$ you dropped the condition that $||y|| \gt 1$ ?  why?.  (furthermore I still don't understand what this have to do with $\sigma_C$

Comment: actually you can keep it, don't need to drop it. the idea is that the first set is the set of points in the interior of the unit ball while the second is the set of the boundary points of the unit ball. together they make the unit ball.

Comment: okay, and now any ideas what this has to do with $\sigma_c$? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, it's been a while, but I have a remark. I think there's a slight oversight in this derivation. When splitting up the set of subgradients, you take the union of two sets, therefore possibly expanding your original set. Suppose, I were to do the same with $y=0$ and $y\neq 0$, then the subdifferential would end up to be all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think the idea is correct, but it should be written down differently.